# invalid module instantiation systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am trying to run this code in eda playground but I am getting following  errors:

```
module array_redu(); 
  byte b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
  int sum,product,b_xor;
  initial
    begin 
      sum =b.sum ;  // y becomes 10 => 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
      product =b.product ;  // y becomes 24 => 1 * 2 * 3 * 4
      b_xor=b.xor with (item+ 4 );  // y becomes 12 => 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^8 
      $display(" Sum is %0d, product is %0d, xor is  %0b",sum,product,b_xor)
      end
endmodule
```

I am getting following errors:

```
design.sv:2: syntax error
design.sv:2: error: Invalid module instantiation
design.sv:3: syntax error
design.sv:3: error: Invalid module instantiation
design.sv:8: syntax error
design.sv:8: error: malformed statement
design.sv:10: syntax error
```

Comment: You wrote (incoherent) software but Verilog is a hardware language. Take a look at this website: http://www.asic-world.com/
It will surely help you understand how to write hardware description language.

Comment: which simulator should I use

Comment: the name of simulator does not matter, they all compile Verilog

Comment: @Krouitch The OP is clearly not trying to design hardware but is playing with the array reduction methods in System Verilog. Array reduction methods are not synthesisable; they are only useful for your testbench. A testbench _is_ software: it stays inside your computer - it's never going to be hardware.

Comment: I don't agree the array reductions methods are not synthesizable. They are just syntactic sugar for writing a longer expression. It might be that some tools do not support it yet. 10 years is not a very long time when it comes to synthesis technology.

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your code using Aldec Riviera Pro on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/sDn). There was only 1 error: you are missing a semi-colon from the end of the line with `$display`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, generally I use Icarus verilog 0.9.7 compiler, do u recommend to use the Aldec Riviera Pro 2015.6. Also I was trying to learn verilog so I was trying to run in some examples just to get hang of it, is it ok to use EDA Playground and above compiler for it.

Comment: @SarangAgrawal Icarus Verilog is a free simulator . It does support System Verilog, but not all of it. Aldec Riviera Pro is a commercial simulator. It supports pretty much all of the language.